# Exporting a file created on the fly using Drupal and PHP

Tags: php, drupal, file-io, drupal-6, export

I am using Drupal 6, and would like to create content that can be exported.  Specifically, I would like to be able to generate some random content string, and then be able to export it to the viewer as a text file.  This would then pop up the usual dialog box from the browser about downloading content (etc.). I don't need to save the file on my server, because the content is constantly changing, and would prefer a solution that could avoid that.

I am a mildly proficient programmer, but not an expert on all of Drupal's functions. So the simpler the answer, the better.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution to my question.  If you use php [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) you will be able to accomplish this.

Here is a snippet of my code that I used to do it.

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain"); //the content type that I am exporting
header("Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=myfilename.txt");
header("Pragma: no-cache"); //I don't want this to be cached because it is constantly changing
echo "My file contents";
exit(0);
```

There are many things to remember when doing this, much of which is documented in the link.

Hopefully this is useful to someone else

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good job for [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [Views Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) and depending on your exact needs, maybe [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

From the Views Bonus page:

> **Views Bonus Pack 1 for Drupal 6**
>
> **Export:**
>        Allows fields to be exported
>   to CSV, DOC, XML and themed text
>   files.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without adding new modules, such as a few lines of php code, or is using a module really the only way to do this?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do it, but it wouldn't follow best Drupal practices. You should really use a contributed module or write your own (if you don't like what's out there) to achieve this functionality.